# Positioning of text and table always at the bottom of a page

Tags: vertical-alignment, positioning

I need to align some content (text/tables) always at the bottom of a page. In between there is a `tableofcontents` - this is obvisouly of relative length. That's why I cannot use absolute distance with `\vspace`

```
\documentclass[15pt, a4paper]{scrartcl}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c|c| } 
 \hline
 Beschluss & Ja & Nein & Enthaltung & Ergebnis \\ \hline
  & X & X & X & X-X-X   \\ 
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\begin{flushleft}
\begin{tabbing}
\footnotesize Beginn: \hspace{1.5cm}\= \footnotesize 18:00 \\
\footnotesize Ende: \> \footnotesize 20:00 \\
\footnotesize Ort: \> \footnotesize Raum \\
\end{tabbing}

\end{flushleft}

\newpage

\section{Topic A}
\section{Topic B}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can't you put into the footer?

Comment: Not in `\cfoot{}` ... there are so many variants. Which one would you choose?

Comment: Give me some minutes to think about it

Comment: `\vspace{\fill}`

Comment: Perfect. This was too easy ...

Comment: @Mac... Yes. David Carlisle is one of our Gurus here!

Comment: But I cannot mark this question as answered now ;) Do you want to post this comment again?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Seems your comment was helpful ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is apparently

```
\vspace{\fill}
```

Comment: Merci beaucoup.